# Which syntax for Unicode strings in VC++?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, unicode-string

How should you use unicode strings in VC++?  Of course you should to #define UNICODE, but what about your strings?

Should the TEXT() or _T() macro be used around all text or should you just put an L in front of strings?  Its my belief that all programs should use unicode these days, so wouldn't it be cleanest to use use the L prefix?

Opinions?

Comment: For the sake of portability and readability, I would strongly discourage the use of Microsoft's magic T-strings, and just use wide strings instead.

Comment: I disagree. *Don't* use wchar_t. It's not portable. Use char and UTF-8.

Comment: @Axel Please tell me how to call the UFT-8 version of `GetWindowText`?

Comment: @Axel: except that the Win32 API doesn't accept UTF-8, which rather limits the portability. `wchar_t` is portable in the same way that an `int` is portable. It's not guaranteed to be the same size on all platforms, and its internal representation may differ, but source code which uses the type to store what it is intended to store will work on all platforms. For cross-platform code, you'll have to faff around with converting between encodings in any case, so I don't really see how utf8 is better

Comment: I would recommend using the same wide/thin as your toolset.  For windows, that's usually wchar_t.  For portable toolsets, usually char.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Is the fact that `_T` is Microsoft-specific actually bothering you? `tchar.h` seems to be pretty independent of anything else, and can be used with little change on any platform. And you can always redefine `_T` to use UTF-8 or whatever so I don't see what the problem with keeping it is...

Comment: @Mehrdad: If you take the Microsoft approach seriously, you'll also use `T` or `_t` versions of almost all C standard library functions, and `_tmain()`. So... portability is seriously shot in the knee.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, I indeed **do** use the `_t` functions. I don't see why portability is an issue, because you can just copy `tchar.h` to other platforms (it's just a bunch of macros), can't you? It shouldn't really depend on anything else, so it's pretty portable.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to make sure your code will compile and work correctly both with and without Unicode, use the `TEXT` or `_T` macros, and call the "default" Win32 function names (for example `CreateWindow`).

If you want to make sure your program always uses the Unicode API, then you should use a `L` prefix in front of your strings, and call the wide versions of Win32 functions (such as `CreateWindowW`).

In the latter case, you'll get unicode behavior whether or not `UNICODE` is defined.
In the former case, your application will change its behavior based on whether `UNICODE` is defined.

I agree with you that the non-unicode versions haven't really been relevant since Win98, so I'd go with the second approach.

Comment: If you are going to go with Unicode and not support ANSI at all then you may as well use `CreateWindow` for sake of readability.

Comment: Except that then your code will break if, for some reason, `UNICODE` is not defined. I figure if you're going to require your strings to be wide (with the `L` prefix), then you might as well do the same, and require your API calls to use wide characters as well. Letting one be controlled by the `UNICODE` macro, while the other ignores it, sounds like a bad idea to me. I'd argue that you should either be consistently explicit, or consistently implicit by relying on whatever the `UNICODE` macro tells you to do. Mixing them is just silly

Comment: Your code is probably broken no matter whether UNICODE is defined or not. I don't see any real extra safety here, just visual clutter.

Comment: @jalf: I'm totally OK with the code failing to compile if the compiler has the wrong settings.  I'd use `CreateWindow(L"HI");` for readability, and it will use the Unicode, or remind me I forgot to set the `UNICODE` define.

Comment: @MooingDuck: You should most certainly **not** say `CreateWindow(L"HI")` -- that's the worst of both worlds! It gives you neither compatibility nor portablity. Either use `CreateWindow(_T("HI"))` or use `CreateWindowW(L"HI")`, but don't mix-and-match.

Comment: CreateWindow(L"HI") is most definitely the think to write, once you have torn yourself away from ANSI.

Comment: @MooingDuck: yeah? And how do you guarantee that it fails to compile? In some cases it may compile fine, and just break at runtime. And honestly. @David: How so? why would my code be broken, if I don't depend on `UNICODE`? And why, exactly is `CreateWindow(L"HI")` "the thing to write"? Saving one character, leaving readers guessing at whether you've even **thought** about UNICODE, and risking your code silently breaking if compiled with the wrong UNICODE setting?

Comment: I think some of you need to think about what readability *means*. To me, code is readable if I can look at it, and understand what it does, and that what it does is the right thing to do. If I see a call to `CreateWindow(L"Hi")`, tehn on the surface of it, you're calling something that might or might not be the unicode version of a function, with something that is **definitely** a unicode argument. And then I have to ask myself "is that intentional? Is this a bug waiting to happen, or did the programmer actually ensure that it's safe?"

Comment: If I see `CreateWindow(_T("Hi"))`, then the code tells me that the programmer thought about how to handle unicode, and wrote the call so that it works with and without unicode. If I see `CreateWindowW(L"Hi")`, then it also tells me that the programmer thought about the question: he chose explicitly to call the unicode function with unicode arguments. To me, rule #1 of readability is "don't leave the reader guessing at whether your code is correct".

Comment: `CreateWindow(L"Hi")` is not readable, because it doesn't tell me what I need to know ("Was the author just lazy, or did he actually think about how to handle Unicode"). When I read the code, I see something that won't always work. I have to look elsewhere to convince myself that the "won't work" cases aren't actually going to occur in practice. If you consider that readable, then you've never actually needed to read code.

Comment: @jalf: With the wrong UNICODE setting, you get a type mismatch, and it will fail to compile.  If it makes you feel better, my code does actually use `_T()` (and unlike the rest of my company's code, mine _can_ compile as both.)

Comment: @MooingDuck: You get a type mismatch, sure, unless a cast is involved. Or unless you find a corner of the Win32 API which expects a void pointer to a type that might contain a string. And I don't need to "feel better". I don't have to read your code, so it doesn't bother me whether or not it's readable. If it makes *you* feel better, I'm not objecting to this because I'm grumpy and annoying, but because I've been bitten by the problems it can cause. And I don't intend to spend more of my life debugging issues that should never occur, just because I was too lazy to type a damn `W`.

Answer (score 1):

Declare Unicode string literals with `L` prefix.

The `TEXT()` or `_T()` macros were for the bad old days when you wanted single source to compile for both Unicode and non-Unicode versions of Windows (Windows 9x). Thankfully you can safely ignore Windows 9x today.

Answer (score 1):

Something I learned a while ago:

### Golden rule:

#### *Don't fight the framework.*

Do what the framework was designed to do -- if you use Windows, use `_T`, to make your code independent of the character type. If you're on Linux, use UTF-8. If you have a cross-platform framework, do whatever it does. But don't try to invent something of your own unless you have a *really* good reason to. (It is simply usually not worth the effort of working against a framework.)

Comment: I don't want to write code independent of the character type. What should I do?

Comment: @David: In Kyle's case, the framework he's coding with is the Windows API, which uses _T macros.  What framework are you coding with?

Comment: @Mooing Duck For the sake of this argument, I'm coding to Windows API which does not require `_T` or `TEXT` macros.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It doesn't *require* them but it was **designed** to be used with them. So instead of fighting it, just go with it.

Comment: @Mehrdad It was not designed to be used with them. They are provided to ease development of single source code that can work target both ANSI and Unicode. If you are targetting just Unicode, as per question, then they are not needed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Er, no -- you're forgetting MBCS. It's indeed designed to allow you to write character-width-independent code, and every function in Windows (*even most new functions*, take note) keeps on following the convention with defining `A` and `W` versions (even if it's not available on Windows 98 or something). IMHO this is because they're encouraging the practice, not because they consider it legacy... otherwise there'd be no point in defining new functions this way.

Comment: Why would I want to do anything with MBCS? I just want to target the Unicode APIs, just as per the question.